# Passing items From DataTable to SQL Where Clause c#

Tags: c#

I have a single column Datatable, I want to pass this datatable in SQL where clause using sqlparametercollection. Please help.
below is my code:

```
public DataTable getCatsByDepts(DataTable _Depts)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=ax12d;Database=DemoDataAx;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Level2 as Category from Mtq_RetailHierarchy Where Level1 IN (@Depts)", conn);
        foreach (DataRow row in _Depts.Rows)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Department", row.Field<string>("Department"));
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable SelectedCatsData = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(SelectedCatsData);
        return SelectedCatsData;

    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or later you can use a [Table Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=ax12d;Database=DemoDataAx;Trusted_Connection=True;");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select Level2 as Category 
                                  from Mtq_RetailHierarchy 
                                  Where Level1 IN (SELECT Department 
                                                   From @Depts)", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Clear();
SqlParameter param cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Depts", _Depts);
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param.TypeName = "dbo.Departments"; //This can either be a table or a User Defined Type


SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable SelectedCatsData = new DataTable();
da.Fill(SelectedCatsData);
return SelectedCatsData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `DataTable` with one column and you want to insert all of your rows in the db-table. A simple approach (also assuming Sql-Server as rdbms):

```
using(var con= new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Table VALUES(@Colname)", con))
{
    con.Open();
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        insertCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Colname", row.Field<string>("Colname"));
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```